# Send cross domain post in dojo

Tags: iframe, dojo, cors

I've tried to execute a `XHR` request and an `iframe` approach, but both lead to a dead end. When I use a `XHR` request I get the (expected) CORS exception, but when I use an `iframe` I'm not able to send JSON data.

Does somebody know how to do this?

```
require(["dojo/request/iframe", "dojo/json"], function(iframe, JSON){
    var json = JSON.stringify({"bindingName":"iasistwebservice", "method":"helloWorld", "params": []});
    iframe("http://10.10.51.49:8080/TestProject/restservices/AsistWebService", {
        data: json,
        handleAs: "json",
      }).then(function(data){
        alert ( data );
      });
});
```

And I've set the appropriate headers(and filters according to https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) on the Tomcat(place where the REST services are running).

Comment: You may need to set the headers in the xhr request.  Here is a [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr) that may help.  There's a "headers" property in the xhr request stuff.  You'll have to use xhr to send the json probably.

Comment: I've tried various headers with the XHR requests, but none of them worked. That's why I tried to reach my goal by using an iframe. When I use the RESTClient plugin for Firefox I'm able to get the response. After this I took a view at the headers with the HTTP Live Headers plugin and I tried to set the same headers as the succesfull request, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that it was a pre flight request(OPTIONS request and after this was verified the POST request would follow).

I've solved the problem by adding the default CORS filter to my Tomcat(Tomcat install directory --> conf --> web.xml):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

NOTE: The CORS filter is integrated in V 7.0.41(correct me if I'm wrong) and above.

The request can be done by using the `XHR` request in Dojo.